# using curl from localhost

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I'm just trying to fetch the yahoo web page. www.yahoo.com

If I run my simple script from my hosted site, it works.

If I try it from my localhost. All I get is a header response with:
"w32.fp.re1.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Wed Apr 27 15:13:48 PDT 2011"

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

function curl_download($Url){

    // is cURL installed yet?
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }


    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Now set some options (most are optional)

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

    // Set a referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");

    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}


print curl_download('http://www.yahoo.com/');
?>
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Would be helpful if you would include source.

Comment: we could help you if you some code :)

Comment: FYI, to return the header in result 1=yes `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the result starts with

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

which means there's a `Location` header in there. And there is:

```
Location: http://nl.yahoo.com/?p=us
```

This is just the response body:

```
<!-- w20.fp.ird.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Wed Apr 27 17:08:09 PDT 2011 -->
```

You need to tell cURL to follow Location headers. That's it.

The name of the option is `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`. Set it to true:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

**PS**
After following `1` Location header, this is the start of the response body when I run your code + FOLLOWLOCATION:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl-NL" class="y-fp-bg y-fp-pg-grad  bkt732">
```

Comment: I actually get a 200 OK, not a 302 redirection.

Comment: If you get the response I got (my 3rd code block), you get a 302. That piece (you call headers) isn't headers but response body. I used your **exact** code in my test.